# When making multiple calls to google sheets API authentication doesn't work for second call: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-sheets-api

So basically what I've done here is I've hijacked the google sheets api node.js quickstart guide for my own purposes. Everything in here works great up until it hits my spreadsheets.batchUpdate and then everything gets wacky.

If I comment out the "auth" initialization in spreadsheets.batchUpdate I get the error message: `The API returned an error: Error: The request does not have valid authentication credentials.`

If I comment out the "auth" initialization in spreadsheets.batchUpdate I get the error message: `The API returned an error: Error: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

All I'm trying to do with these calls is get some data out of the sheet and then delete the rows after but I can't figure out this authentication issue.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var updateDB = require('./updateDB.js');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var splitData;


// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json';
var array = [];

var run = {
  runQuickstart : function() {
    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
      // Google Sheets API.
      authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
 * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
 */
function listMajors(auth) {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: '1EV8S8AaAmxF3vP0F6RWxKIUlvF6uFEmsrOFWA1oNBYI',
    range: 'Form Responses 1!A3:X3',
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var rows = response.values;
    //splitData = rows.split(',');
    updateDB.inputFormToDB.apply(this, rows);
    if (rows.length == 0) {
      console.log('No data found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Form Responses');
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        console.log('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s', row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23]);
      }


      var spreadsheetId = '1EV8S8AaAmxF3vP0F6RWxKIUlvF6uFEmsrOFWA1oNBYI';
      var requests = [];
      requests.push({
        "deleteDimension": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": spreadsheetId,
            "dimension": "ROWS",
            "startIndex": 0,
            "endIndex": 3
          }
        }
      });
      var batchUpdateRequest = {requests: requests}
      var test = auth;
      sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        // auth: test,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        resource: batchUpdateRequest
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }
      });

    }
  });
}

module.exports = run;
```

Comment: @Rubén fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` will give you read rights. 
You need to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` scope to update the sheet.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly

```
Allows read-only access to the user's sheets and their properties.
```

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

```
Allows read/write access to the user's sheets and their properties.
```

Comment: tried this fix :(. First changed the link in SCOPES to the second one you listed... that didn't work. Noticed the comments that said `// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json` so deleted all credentials on google's developers console... now I keep getting an error `The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client`.

Comment: You need to delete the credentials file on your system, not in the developers console. Start a new quickstart, and copy your changes into that quickstart. This is probably the quickest way to get it working again.

Comment: UPDATE!!! So I fixed my credentials issue and then reset the SCOPES and now it mostly works. I'm able to send the request now but I'm getting a new error. It's unrelated to this post so I would just like to thank you for helping me get read/write access :). Now I just need to figure out how to send the right write command to delete row 2 of my sheet....